# Errors in Delphi while trying to load procedures from dll

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2

I have a problem while loading procedures from a dll, either when loading it dynamically or statically. When I put procedures from dll to my unit, everything works fine. When I try to do it with dll it gives me

> First chance exception at $00526399. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00526399: read of address 0x00000390'. Process Project1.exe (21988)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls,Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Refresh;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

type
plist = ^element;
element = record
  artist,title,genre: string[20];
  year,grade: integer;
  wsk: plist;
end;
database = file of element;

var
base: database;
first: plist;
handler: HModule;
{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.Refresh();
var
current: plist;
begin
  ListView1.Clear;
  current:= first;
  while current<>nil do
  begin
    with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
      Caption:=current^.artist;
      SubItems.Add(current^.title);
      SubItems.Add(current^.genre);
      SubItems.Add(IntToStr(current^.year));
      SubItems.Add(IntToStr(current^.grade));
    end;
    current:=current^.wsk;
  end;
end;



procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var Save: procedure;
begin
handler:=LoadLibrary('lib.dll');
try
  @Save:=GetProcAddress(handler, PChar(2));
  if @Save = nil then raise Exception.Create('Load nie dziala');
  Save();
finally
FreeLibrary(handler);
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
Load: procedure;
begin
handler:=LoadLibrary('lib.dll');
try
  @Load:=GetProcAddress(handler, PChar(1));
  if @Load = nil then raise Exception.Create('Load nie dziala');
  Load();
finally
FreeLibrary(handler);
end;
Refresh();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
el: element;
Add: procedure(el:element);
begin
el.artist:=Edit1.Text;
el.title:=Edit2.Text;
el.genre:=Edit3.Text;
el.year:=StrToInt(Edit4.Text);
el.grade:=StrToInt(Edit5.Text);
handler:=LoadLibrary('lib.dll');
try
  @Add:=GetProcAddress(handler, PChar(3));
  if @Add = nil then raise Exception.Create('Load nie dziala');
  Add(el);
finally
FreeLibrary(handler);
Refresh();
{Form2:=TForm2.Create(Form1);
Form2.ShowModal;
Form2.Free;}
end;
end;
end.
```

The dll file looks like this:

```
  library lib;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

type plist = ^element;
element = record
  artist,title,genre:string[20];
  year,grade:integer;
  wsk: plist;
end;
database = file of element;

var
first: plist;
base: database;

procedure add(el: element); stdcall;
var current,tmp: plist;
begin
New(current);
current^ := el;
current^.wsk := nil;
if first = nil then
begin
  first:=current;
end else
begin
  tmp:=first;
  while tmp^.wsk<>nil do
  begin
    tmp:=tmp^.wsk;
  end;
  tmp^.wsk:=current;
end;

end;

procedure load();stdcall;
var
  el: element;
  i: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(base, 'baza.dat');
  if not FileExists('baza.dat') then
  begin
    Rewrite(base);
  end else
  begin
    Reset(base);
    for i := 0 to FileSize(base)-1 do
    begin
        read(base, el);
        add(el);
    end;
  end;
  CloseFile(base);
end;

procedure save();stdcall;
var
current: plist;
el: element;
begin
  AssignFile(base, 'baza.dat');
  Rewrite(base);
  current:=first;
  while current<>nil do
  begin
    el:=current^;
    el.wsk:=nil;
    write(base, el);
    current:= current^.wsk;
  end;
end;

exports
add index 1,
load index 2,
save index 3;
begin
end.
```

It also shows me an error:

> Expected ';' but received and identifier 'index' at line 91

But exports are done like I red on web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious errors are:

- You don't perform much error checking. You assume that the calls to `LoadLibrary` always succeed.
- The calling conventions don't match. You use `stdcall` in the DLL and `register` in the executable.
- The ordinals don't match. In the DLL it is add (1), load (2) and save (3). In the executable you have  add (3), load (1) and save (2).
- You load and unload the DLL every time you call functions from the DLL. That means that the global variables in the DLL that hold your state are lost each time the DLL is unloaded.

Frankly this code is a real mess. I suggest that you do the following:

1. Switch to load time linking using the function names rather than ordinals. This means to use the `external` keyword in the executable. This will greatly simplify your code by removing all those calls to `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` etc. If runtime linking is needed, you can add it later using the `delayed` keyword.
2. Stop using global state in the DLL and instead pass information back and forth between modules. Remove all global variables. But make sure you don't pass Delphi objects back and forth.
3. Use `PChar` rather than short strings across the module boundary.
4. Stop using linked lists and dynamic allocation. That's hard to get right. Use `TList<T>` in the DLL to store the list of elements.